# how dataframe get same groupby with window function

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I'm using the DataFrame part of PySpark to analyze data from Apache Kafka. I'm having some trouble and need some assistance.

```py
    from pyspark.sql import functions

    # selected_df is dataframe come from kafka use spark.readStream.format("kafka")...

    windowed_group_1 = selected_df.withWatermark("kafka_time", "10 minutes").groupBy(functions.window("kafka_time", "10 seconds", "5 seconds"))

    windowed_group_2 = selected_df.withWatermark("kafka_time", "10 minutes").groupBy(functions.window("kafka_time", "10 seconds", "5 seconds"))
```

Are the two groupby the same window function? they are in the same options.

If not how do I accomplish this?

```
windowed_group_1 == windowed_group_2
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is usefull what i want, the window function default take 1970-01-01T00:00:00 as the reference frame whenever use time window.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

a = labeled_df.groupBy(func.window("timestamp", "60 minute"), "proto").count().show(100, truncate=False)

b = labeled_df.groupBy(func.window("timestamp", "60 minute"), "proto").count().show(100, truncate=False)
```

the result a and b is same

```
a
+------------------------------------------+---------+-----+
|window                                    |proto    |count|
+------------------------------------------+---------+-----+
|[2010-06-13 08:00:00, 2010-06-13 09:00:00]|UDP      |1803 |
|[2010-06-13 02:00:00, 2010-06-13 03:00:00]|TCP      |22579|
|[2010-06-13 09:00:00, 2010-06-13 10:00:00]|TCP      |2637 |
|[2010-06-13 02:00:00, 2010-06-13 03:00:00]|IPv6-ICMP|453  |
|[2010-06-13 02:00:00, 2010-06-13 03:00:00]|UDP      |1183 |
|[2010-06-13 03:00:00, 2010-06-13 04:00:00]|UDP      |1467 |


b
+------------------------------------------+---------+-----+
|window                                    |proto    |count|
+------------------------------------------+---------+-----+
|[2010-06-13 08:00:00, 2010-06-13 09:00:00]|UDP      |1803 |
|[2010-06-13 02:00:00, 2010-06-13 03:00:00]|TCP      |22579|
|[2010-06-13 09:00:00, 2010-06-13 10:00:00]|TCP      |2637 |
|[2010-06-13 02:00:00, 2010-06-13 03:00:00]|IPv6-ICMP|453  |
|[2010-06-13 02:00:00, 2010-06-13 03:00:00]|UDP      |1183 |
|[2010-06-13 03:00:00, 2010-06-13 04:00:00]|UDP      |1467 |
```